# The probability of a bit being corrupt is $0.00015$. If there are $16$ bits, what is the probability that at least one is corrupt?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm pretty sure I've solved this correctly but I don't know why it works.

The negation is easy: "all $16$ bits are valid", which is just $(1-0.00015)^{16}$, so then the correct solution would be $1-(1-0.00015)^{16}\approx 0.002397$.

Here's how I tried to confirm it:
The event "At least one bit is corrupt" is one of the events:
(1) $15$ valid, $1$ corrupt
(2) $14$ valid, $2$ corrupt
...
(15) $0$ valid, $16$ corrupt

Since these events are dependent, the total probability is just the sum of their probabilities. Is the probability of (1) equal to $\binom{16}{1}(1-0.00015)^{15}(0.00015)$? Why are we multiplying by $\binom{16}{1}=16$? We have $16$ bits, the probability of $15$ of them being valid and $1$ being corrupt should be $(1-0.00015)^{15}(0.00015)$?

Then I also think that the probability of (2) is $\binom{16}{2}(1-0.00015)^{14}(0.00015)^2$, but I dont know why we are multiplying by $\binom{16}{2}$. We can think of $\binom{16}{2}$ as the amount of combinations of the $16$ bits, but I don't see how that is related to calculating the probability here.

I'm pretty sure the total probability is $$\sum^{16}_{i=1}\binom{16}{i}(1-0.00015)^{16-i}(0.00015)$$ (can be confirmed with binomial theorem).

Can this be explained with set theory?

edit: I first solved this with the inclusion-exclusion principle, considering the events "1bit corrupt", "2bits corrupt" ... "16bits corrupt", since these are not independent you have to use the inclusion-exclusion principle. (that's also where I got the binomial but I dont see how it makes sense when solving the problem with these independent events)

edit2:
Can (1) be thought of like this?
For each bit, there is a $(1-0.00015)^{15}(0.00015)$ chance of it being the only corrupt bit. There are 16 of these events, and they are mutually exclusive, so their total probability is their sum, which is just the same as multiplying by $16$.

Similarly for (2):
The probability of exactly $2$ being corrupt. There are $\binom{16}{2}$ possible pairs of bits, and for each one the probability of them being the only corrupt bits is $(1-0.00015)^{15}(0.00015)^2$, since these events are mutually exclusive, we add all of their probaiblites, which is same as multiplying by $\binom{16}{2}$

Comment: The probability of having an error in a single bit *at a specific position* is  $(1-e)^{15}e$ but there are 16 positions.

Comment: This is just a binomial process, so you can sum the probabilities (for exactly one corrupted bit, exactly two, and so on).  The probability of exactly $k$ corrupted bits is $\binom {16}k(.00015)^k(1-.00015)^{16-k}$.  I am assuming independence here, as I presume you intended to.  Without that assumption (or something along those lines), not much can be said.